# Instance an array from a type in go

Tags: go

How can I instance an array with a given type?

I get the type this way:

```
type := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
```

But I don't know how to get an instance of an array with this type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reflect.MakeSlice](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeSlice) for that:

```
type := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
reflectSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(type, sliceLength, sliceCapacity)
```

Comment: In case he really meant array and not slice, then he'll have to wait for [CL4111](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/4111).